# What are factors in the Visual Design of a Language?

Tags: typography, symbols, language

Just to be clear, I'm talking about something like typography, though in most cases typography relates to the redesigning of a set of symbols, not the designing of a set of symbols.

I'm guessing that someone has done research on this when creating a [constructed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language), but I've never found any, or been able to discover any factors that would be best practices.

Comment: Please explain where the UX question is in your post.

Comment: Darmok and Jalad at Tanagra. (Translated: Be more specific or I don't know how this relates to UX design)

Comment: @JohnGB: A written language is an interface to unspoken words. All languages have a set of visual rules, which one would hope were designed to support clear expression. What are these rules?

Comment: @JohnGB - I'm still trying to find the question in the post period, UX or not.

Comment: @Ben Brocka: See comment above to JohnGB. It's still not clear, please add clarification. Thanks!

Comment: @Charles Boyung: Updated the question to be "What are factors in the Visual Design of a Language?"

Comment: The vocabulary and syntax used in the text of an interface are important parts of the user experience. But it doesn't sound like you're asking that.

Comment: @Alex Feinman: Correct, that's not what I'm talking about. To me, an interface is not limited to a screen, it's anything that functions as an interface. In this case, we're using language as an interface to each other to express our thoughts. Each written language by design or not functions as an visual interface. I'm not 100% sure what I'm looking for because it's not common to visually design a language.

Comment: @blunders, I agree with what you say about interfaces. You may be interested in research we've done on language as a 'mediating artifact'.

Language design is more than visual design, however. In any case, this actually seems like a better fit for a Language SE site.

Comment: @blunders I can see where you're coming from in a Cognitive Science, more specifically Semiotics. I'm still not sure many here can help you though

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiotics

Comment: @Alex Feinman: All I'm requesting is visual themes in existing languages that might be inferred to "best practices" or "lessons Learned", not a how to on creating a constructed language. There are lots of questions UX SE that provide proof this question is relevant.

Comment: @Charles Boyung: I'll take your lack of followup to mean I've addressed your concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glyph shapes are actually fairly arbitrary and probably aren't tied to innate readability. Most of the glyphs you and I know as Latin script came about from ancient Phoenician, which chose character shapes not for scanning, but for their similarity to a range of animals, plants and everyday objects.

The letter A, for example, comes from the Phoenician character aleph [image], which is modelled on an Ox's head (and as you'd expect, can be used to mean a cow, bull or calf).

Even individual fonts don't show as many innate readability features as we once suspected. Early studies in the 50s and 60s indicated that users could parse serif fonts far faster than sans-serif, but in the 80s and 90s that trend had reversed. The usual explanation is that familiarity, not glyph shape, is what principally determined readability.

Comment: +1 @Jimmy Breck-McKye: Agree that most visual interfaces to languages were not "designed" - but that does not mean it's not possible.